# Pass variable value as Column name in SPARK Sql/Pyspark?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am a beginner to PYSPARK/SPARKSQL and have a requirement below.

DataFrame:

| Dataframe | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Emp | Name1 | Name2 | Address |
| Job | Doj | Role | DOB |

I have iterated the above dataframe and assigned values to variables, and I need to pass variable values as columns to another DF as below:

```py
First_Name = Config.alias('a').select(a.col1).filter("Rownumber = '" + str(i) + "'" ).first()[0]
print("First_Name :" + First_Name )

Last_Name = Config.alias('a').select(a.col2).filter("Rownumber = '" + str(i) + "'" ).first()[0]
print("Last_Name :" + Last_Name )
```

Now the `First_Name`, and `Last_Name` variable holds the column name of the below Dataframe `Emp`,

Need the dataframe as below:

```py
DF = Emp.select(col('Name1'),col('Name2'),col('Address'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood the question properly. But as per my understanding, you are getting first_name and last_name from the corresponding dataframes and you want to use it with `col` function in **DF** `dataframe`.

If that's the case, you can use python's str.format as below:

```py
DF = emp.select(col("{}".format(First_Name)), 
        col("{}".format(Last_Name)))
```